# Images created by a pair of perpendicular mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection

Let's assume we're given a pair of perpendicular mirrors. Let us set a system of coordinates as shown on the picture - the position of an object is given by $(x_p, y_p)$. Of course we would observe two images ($P'$ and $P''$ on my sketch). However, these two aren't the only ones. There is also third image $P'''$, whose position isn't obvious for me. Intuitively, I would guess that there is some kind of point reflection around $(0,0)$.
**The question is thus: what is the position of the image $P'''?$**
I tried to solve it like this. In figure 2 I drew way traveled by a light beam if it first hits the vertical mirror. In figure 3 there is shown a way traveled by beam which reflects form the horizontal mirror at first. Angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are completely independent of each other. Let's have a closer look at these two situations.

### I (fig.2)

Let's do some simple geometry.
$$\tan(90°-\alpha)=\frac{c}{x_p} \Rightarrow c=x_p\tan\alpha$$
$$a=y_p-c=y_p-x_p\tan\alpha$$
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{a}{b} \Rightarrow b=\frac{y_p}{\tan\alpha}-x_p$$
Way of the beam "on the over side of the mirror" is given by a graph of some linear function $f(x)=Ax+B$. $A=\tan\alpha$ (obviously) and $B$ can be easily found using a relation $f(b)=0$. Hence we obtain
$$f(x)=x\tan\alpha+x_p\tan\alpha-y_p.$$

### II (fig.3)

We do everything like previously obtaining $a'=x_p-y_p\tan\beta$ and $b'=\frac{x_p}{\tan\beta}-y_p$. Graph of the function $g(x)=A'x+B'$ has the same geometrical meaning as before, and $A'=\tan(90°-\beta)$. We shall use the following relation
$$
g(0)=b' \Rightarrow B'=b'.
$$
Thus we have
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{\tan\beta}+\frac{x_p}{\tan\beta}-y_p
$$

### Discussion

If graphs of these two functions meet, the point where they intersect can be found comparing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. This yields:
$$
\frac{x}{\tan\beta}+\frac{x_p}{\tan\beta}=x\tan\alpha+x_p\tan\alpha.
$$
There is a huge problem with this equation. Because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two independent values, we cannot solve it. Moreover, it seems to be incorrect. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same slope, according to the sketch, they should never intersect. If, however, we consider $\alpha=90°-\beta$ (which provides the same multipliers for x) we get an identity. So finally: where's the mistake? Are these equations valid? What is the position of the third image $P'''$ in such system of mirrors?  Thanks in advance!
*P.S.* Applying the same method for $P'$ and $P''$ gives nice results, namely $(-x_p,y_p)$ and $(x_p,-y_p)$ respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equations for $f$ and $g$ are correct. If these two lines intersect, then $f(x) = g(x)$, or
$$ \tan \alpha (x + x_p) + y_p = \cot \beta (x + x_p) + y_p $$
$$ (\tan \alpha - \cot \beta ) (x + x_p) = 0. $$
If this equation is to hold regardless of the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which are independent, $x + x_p$ must be zero. Otherwise, changing $\alpha$ or $\beta$ will cause the left hand side to change, but not the right hand side. Now, with $x = -x_p$, you will find
$$ y = f(-x_p) = g(-x_p) = -y_p. $$
Therefore the image you are after is located at $(-x_p, -y_p)$.

However, there is a fundamental problem with your approach. At point $P'''$, there are really two overlapping images: the image through mirror 1 of the image through mirror 2, and the image through mirror 2 of the image through mirror 1. When the mirrors are perpendicular, these two images are located at the same point: $(-x_p, -y_p)$. This is why setting $f(x) = g(x)$ worked in your approach: these lines go through the same point. However, when the mirrors are not perpendicular, these two images will appear at different points, which complicates things.

What you should realize is that $y = f(x)$ defines a family of lines passing through the image through the horizontal mirror of the image through the vertical mirror, so $f(x)$ by itself is sufficient to determine the image coordinates. For clarity, let $f_\alpha(x)$ be equal to $f(x)$, with the subscript indicating the parameter $\alpha$. The location of the image doesn't depend on $\alpha$, so for two different angles $\alpha$ and $\alpha '$, we have
$$f_\alpha (x) = f_{\alpha '} (x) $$
$$ \tan \alpha (x + x_p) - y_p = \tan \alpha ' (x + x_p) - y_p $$
$$ (\tan \alpha - \tan \alpha ')(x + x_p) = 0. $$

For the same reasons as before, this equation requires $x = -x_p$, and then $y = f(-x_p) = -y_p$. This solution can be repeated for $g(x)$, which will yield the same coordinates, meaning the two images are co-located.

Finally, as for your question about what happens if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same slope: this only happens when you shoot the beam right at the intersection of the two mirrors. In this case, the lines defined by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ overlap. They still go through the location of the images, and there are no problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel like a fool, not seeing that $(x+x_p)\tan\alpha=(x+x_p)\cot\beta$ could be written as $(\tan\alpha-\tan\beta)(x+x_p)=0$... I am especially grateful for pointing out that my approach worked by chance; I would be completely wrong otherwise.